# Selectable sink or source Input

Tags: npn, pnp

I'm looking for a circuit that I can add to a universal Input board that will be able to handle a 5-24v input PNP or an NPN 0v signal that I can connect to my arduino. 
I was considering using an optocoupler and then with the use of some jumpers, select what side is tied high or low and which side becomes the "input"
Perhaps there is a circuit I can use or a chip with this functionality?

Im thinking the MAX22191 chip might work for me. I can add some jumpers that would ground the chip and then use the "IN" signal as the field connector for PNP and if I need NPN, I would change the jumpers that would connect "IN" to 5v and use the ground connection as the field connector.

Comment: All logic levels need to be defined with tolerances, {voltage, current, hysteresis , isolation, delay time} before a design can start. But there aren't any standard interfaces obvious from your question to support a universal solution.

Comment: You should write more details. For example, although I know from experience that there are some devices that provide so-called "NPN" or "PNP" outputs (which when I first saw the terms being used brought the wrong images to my mind, corrected only by further reading of details), it won't be clear to others that there even is such a standard nomenclature in certain industries. Links to standards or, at least, some devices illustrating the practice in appropriate industries would go a long way in helping others. I'm not sure the MAX22191 is what you want, though, given your voltage range.